# What is the best way to use union or extend when I have a similar context in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

So I have a function that receives 2 types of objects, something like this:

```js
const canBeGenericOrDefaultData = {
  id: 123,
  pointData: {
  square: 'x145',
  triangle: 'y145'
  }
}


function submitHandler(canBeGenericOrDefaultData: AllTheDatas | GenericAllTheDatas):
  buildPointData(canBeGenericOrDefaultData.pointData)
  // do something
```

```js
function buildPointData(pointData: AllTheDatas["pointData"] | GenericAllTheDatas["pointData"])
```

My interfaces:

```js
interface AllTheDatas{
 id: string
 pointData: {
  square: string
  triangle: string
 }
}

interface GenericAllTheDatas{
 id: string
 pointData: {
  square: string
  triangle: string
 }
}
```

Context:
We have 2 similar interfaces because we have 1 default page (in production) and another generic page that's still in development. We didn't want to touch or change the structure of the default page, so we're just trying to share the submit handlers of both pages in this case to avoid the duplication of the service/button handlers.

The question is: Is is correct to declare that way every time I call a function inside of the submitHandler or do we have another easier way to type that?

In this context, if I add a new type like:

```
interface AllTheDatas{
 id: string
 pointData: {
  square: string
  triangle: string
  newForm: string
 }
}

interface GenericAllTheDatas{
 id: string
 pointData: {
  square: string
  triangle: string
 }
}
```

and start to receive both objects

```
const defaultData = {
  id: 123,
  pointData: {
  square: 'x145',
  triangle: 'y145',
  newForm: 'x1234'
  }
}

const genericData = { 
  id: 123,
  pointData: {
  square: 'x145',
  triangle: 'y145'
  }
}
```

Can I just create another interface and extend to GenericAllTheDatas? is that a good practice?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to declare the same type twice. Create a second type only when it actually becomes different. And yes, when *adding* a new property, it's fine to simply extend the interface, in particular when the original one will *never* change, as you say.

Comment: An alternative would be to simply add *optional* properties to the type. The only downside with this solution is that you won't have a name for the type of exclusively new objects.

Comment: Btw, `AllTheDatas["pointData"] | GenericAllTheDatas["pointData"]` = `(AllTheDatas | GenericAllTheDatas)["pointData"]`

Comment: I actually wanted to use only 1 type, but we're using folder structure like: /GenericForm/GenericForm.types.tsx and /DefaultForm/DefaultForm.types.tsx and those 2 interfaces are separated in respective folders and I thought it would be "best way" to avoid changing the DefaultForm structure.

Comment: a) change your folder structure or b) just define a type alias then, `type AllTheDatas = GenericAllTheDatas;` (not sure which way round, didn't you say the default `AllTheDatas` won't change? But it's the one to which you added the new property) where the new module imports the old one.

Comment: But I liked your third comment, thank you

Comment: Yea, at this time (while implementing the GenericAllTheDatas), we're not going to add anything, but in the second stage after launching the generic form to production, they're planning to add one more field `newForm` which will mess if I just add type `AllTheDatas = GenericAllTheDatas`

Comment: If you're planning to add properties to `GenericAllTheDatas`, please fix your question, which did add the `newForm` property to `AllTheDatas`. As I said, define the new (likely to change) type using the old (immutable) type. Then when you actually need to add the property, just change the alias into an `extends`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a type instead of an interface until that interface is different. Note that under the hood interfaces and types are the same.

```
type GenericAllTheDatas = AllTheDatas;
```